# CouchDB - aggregate multiple values in the reduce step

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I am trying to aggregate multiple values emitted from my map in a custom reduce function( rereduce enabled) but I get null values in the result except for few datapoints where I see 0s., Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

My data emitted is in this format:

```
Key:"dateX" Values:"{'a':435, 'b':5645}"
Key:"dateX" Values:"{'a':8451, 'b':9245}"
Key:"dateX" Values:"{'a':352, 'b':450}"

Key:"dateY" Values:"{'a':5675, 'b':1245}"
Key:"dateY" Values:"{'a':4455, 'b':620}"
```

I want to aggregate/sum the values of both a & b for dateX and dateY, my map-reduce is:

```
"map": "function(doc){emit(doc.logDate, {'a': doc.a, 'b': doc.b} );}",

"reduce": "function(key, values, rereduce) { 
                    var total = {tA:0, tB:0}; 
                    if(rereduce){ 
                        for(i=0; i<values.length; i++)
                        { 
                            total.tA += values[i].a; 
                            total.tB += values[i].b;
                        } 
                        return total;
                    } 
                    total.tA = sum(values.a); 
                    total.tB = sum(values.b); 
                    return total; }"
------------------------
Results:
dateX        {tA: 0, tB: 0} 
dateY        {tA: null, tB: null}   
dateZ        {tA: null, tB: null}
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all function sum expects an array as an argument instead of values.a which is undefined, so you can try

```
total.tA = sum(values.map(function (value) {return value.a}));
total.tB = sum(values.map(function (value) {return value.b}));
```

Or something like

```
values.reduce(function (t, value) {
    t.tA += value.a;
    t.tB += value.b;
    return t;
}, total);
```

Also, when rereduce flag is enabled means that the reduce function works with already reduced values, so

```
for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) { 
    total.tA += values[i].tA; //not a
    total.tB += values[i].tB; //not b
}
```

Also, you should add `else` to prevent double execution in rereduce case

```
if (rereduce) {
   //
} else {
  //
}
```

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html#reduce

Comment: Thanks @the4lt I will try this, for my issue I fixed it by making {tA:0, tB:0};  to the same format as"{'a':4455, 'b':620}", in this way the reduce method works correctly and I guess it does not trigger rereduce so I am able to sum with for loop and avoided sum() function to aggregate.